# ValueObjects Django

Tags: python, django

Bom dia pessoal, estou iniciando agora com Python e Django e me surgiu uma dúvida na criação dos meus modelos.
Eu gostaria de criar algo do tipo:

Pessoa(models.Model)

- Nome
- ...
- Endereço

Endereço()

- Logradouro
- Bairro
- ...

Ou seja, separar o endereço como um value object para poder usar em mais de um modelo. No banco de dados os campos de dentro da classe de endereço serão persistidos dentro da tabela de Pessoas e de outras entidades que possam surgir (Empresa, Cliente, "Qualquer um que possa ter endereço"). Assim evitar duplicar todos campos de endereço para cada modelo que precise.

Vi que daria para fazer setando o Meta do endereço para abstract e herdando Pessoa de Endereço. Só que se eu quiser fazer mais ValueObjects terei que herdar de várias classes para isso, gostaria de saber se existe uma forma mais correta.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo que o endereço seja o mesmo entre várias pessoas, sugiro que deixe como atributo da classe Pessoa. A menos que morem na mesma residência/prédio, não teremos tantos casos iguais. Vai facilitar a legibilidade e diminuir mais uma relação entre tabelas no banco.

Além disso, se estiver trabalhando com um formulário que vá enviar essas informações, fica difícil padronizar a forma como o usuário inputa os dados ('Rua xx' vs 'R. xx', etc).

Answer (score 1):

Quando me encontro nesse tipo de situação, eu sempre tenho duas opções:

1. Relacionar o item
2. Criar uma tabela separada para o endereço e adicionar a chave estrangeira no cliente.
3. Criar uma tabela Endereço e fazer com a que a tabela Cliente herde de Endereço. Assim ela teria os campos de endereço, mais os campos de cliente.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você procura é uma relação many-to-one. Poderia criar o model "Endereço" separado e criar um campo [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) no model "Pessoa"

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    [...]
    endereco = models.ForeignKey('Endereco', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```